# How to programmatically create Ribbon and add controls to it?

Tags: c#, ms-office, ribbon

I want to have a single ribbon in microsoft office, in which I will have all my add-ins.
Let's say there are 2 add-ins, both are a single button on the ribbon, which then open a winform.
The user installs the first add-in, the program checks for an installed ribbon, since there isn't any, it adds the ribbon and the button, which calls the add-ins function.

Then the user installs the second add-in later, which, instead of adding the same ribbon, checks if there is already a ribbon with the same name installed, and if there is, it only adds the button to the already installed ribbon, if there isn't(somehow the first add-in was uninstalled or something) it adds the ribbon with the button.

So I thought that in the ThisAddin_Startup event I instantiate a "RibbonController" class.
In the RibbonController class i would check for the ribbons existence. (Every addin would have a RibbonController class)

Since I'm fairly new in the MS Office Add-in programming zone, i need help accessing the ribbons objects and creating it programmatically if it wasn't installed earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a Ribbon.xml for every addin, that has the same structure.
I've set a "namespace" in every ribbon.xml, that will help the controls to be added to the same tab, everytime.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns:x="NAMESPACE FOR EVERY TAB"> //the namespaces abreviation is "x"
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idQ="x:tab1" label="CommonTab" >
            ....
```

Then I set the tabs idQ with the "x:" prefix so it will know the namespace. From every add-in that uses the same xml structure, the controls from the tab will be added to a single tab.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Add In Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/) at our work place. It's really easy to use and does everything. It's paid though.

Also please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135480/office-add-in-ribbons-same-tab-with-2-addins) answer.

Comment: And it can do the exact same thing as I was requesting?
I would really like to do it without any third-party stuff, but if it's the only way, i have to convince my boss to buy it.

Comment: It can do whole lot more. You can do it your self but you can't beat the price. For $450 you get tools that make your life much easier. I don't work for add-in-express but because I really like the tool as I use them at my work place.

Comment: Thank you Mayank!
The thing is, that I would really like to know a more basic approach to this, without third-party applications

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but sadly it's not exactly what I wanted.
I can't add add-in specific controls to that shared ribbon from the add-in itself.